# Download/Install apk Version 23>

Tags: android, download, apk

After reading multiple post concerning this subject I have been able to put together the info needed to download an update for my apk and have it install. This is successful for versions under 23. After reading more post I discovered for versions 23> there is a slight difference in the way to execute the install. I have put together this info in the following code but I am still encountering a problem with the version 23>.  I pretty much understand what the code is doing, but I have no idea why it fails to run.

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                String PATH= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() +"/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "maga.apk");
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    Log.i("SCROLLS ", "file exist-delete");
                    outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                   }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    Log.i("SCROLLS ", "file exist");
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                     File toInstall=new File(Uri.parse(PATH+"maga.apk").getPath());
                    Log.i("SCROLLS ", "toInstall "+ toInstall);
                    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", toInstall);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    File toInstall = new File(PATH, "maga" + ".apk");
                    Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SCROLLS ", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When executed on an emulator with Version <23 all works. On an emulator over 23, the progress gets into the If statement and sets the toInstall value but nothing happens after that. The only thing I see in Logcat resembling and error that pertains to this is

```
03-24 01:35:16.562 5300-5300/com.google.android.packageinstaller E/InstallStart: Requesting uid 10079 needs to declare permission android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

Looking into this it's my understanding that this permission is for system apps so adding it to Manifest does no good. Is there something missing from my code or a permission? I have added the provider to the manifest and the provider_paths.xml file to the project. Thanks for any help.

Comment: _this permission is for system apps so adding it to Manifest does no good._ but you need to add it to manifest if you want it

Comment: I still have no idea as to why my code fails on version over 23>. In mean time I dropped target to 22, not ideal but for now it will have to do.